# Assign worksheet name to function/sub argument

Tags: vba, excel

Although a lot of posts explain how to assign a whole sheet to a variable, i couldn't find one that explains how to assign the *name only* to a sub/function *argument*.

I need to be able to do this because I want to easily switch between worksheets just by changing an argument in my sub/function.

I have 3 routines :

```
'Sub to run the code and call the other routines
Public Sub runthecode()

Dim ID As Range, Result As Range

ResultLocation = Cell_Address("Pass Rates", "Functional Text", "fra-FRA")
IDLocation = Cell_Address("Regression URLs", "Text-Based Functional", "fra-FRA")


MsgBox ResultLocation

End Sub

-------
' Sub to find, by 2 way look up, the address of a cell

Public Function Cell_Address(WorksheetName As String, Runtype As String, Language As String) As String

With Sheets(WorksheetName)

Call Find_String(Runtype)

Runtype_Row = Selection.Row

Call Find_String(Language)

Language_Column = Selection.Column

Cell_Address = Cells(Runtype_Row, Language_Column).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

MsgBox Cell_Address

End With

End Function

-------
' Sub to find a specific string

Public Sub Find_String(Search_String As String)

    Cells.Find(What:=Search_String, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, 
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, 
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

End Sub
```

In *runthecode* I call the *Cell_Address* Function. As you can see, I have a String variable named WorksheetName which I try to pass in the segment

```
With Sheets(WorksheetName)
```

Because I assume that it'd be the same thing as saying

```
With Sheets("Pass Rates")
```

However, it always seems to take my first worksheet (Pass Rates) and never goes to the second worksheet (Regression URLs) and gives me the error 91 "Object variable not set" (which is just because it can't find the next Runtype string (Text-Based Functional" in the first sheet since that string is only in the second sheet).

**Does anyone know how I can pass the worksheet name in a function argument and use it to switch between sheets when calling that function ?**

Thanks !

Comment: In `Cell_Address`, you have your `With Sheets(WorksheetName)...End With` block - but then you immediately call `Find_String` - _which has an implicit reference to the `ActiveSheet` - i.e. `ActiveSheet.Cells.Find`. `Cell_address` and `Find_String` should be combined into 1 `Function`

Comment: Furthermore you never use your `With` block. You could remove the `With` and `End With` entirely and the code would execute exactly the same.

Comment: Your usage of `activesheet` and `selection` will cause all sorts of issues here. What is the `activesheet` at the time that this code executes? What is the `selection`? Also you say `Cells(RunType_Row, Language_Column)` but... `Cells` of what... if you want that to be the `Cells()` of the sheet in your `With` block then that should be `.Cells(Runtype_Row, Language_Column).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)` (notice the `.` in the front)

Comment: Worksheet..Name?

Comment: And then just as @BigBen notes you use that `Cells()` again in your `Find_String`. `Cells` of what range/sheet though? You are not being explicit and telling VBA what `Cells` is referencing so it defaults to `ActiveSheet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @JNevill & @BigBen for your feedback and solutions; I have it all working now :)

Here is the working code :

```
Public Sub runthecode()

Dim http As Object, JSON As Object
Dim ID As String, Result As String
Dim IDLocation As String, ResultLocation As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

IDLocation = Cell_Address("Regression URLs", "Text-Based Functional", "fra-FRA")
ResultLocation = Cell_Address("Pass Rates", "Functional Text", "fra-FRA")


ID = Sheets("Regression URLs").Range(IDLocation).Value
Result = Sheets("Pass Rates").Range(ResultLocation).Value

MsgBox Result
MsgBox ResultLocation

End Sub
______________________

Public Function Cell_Address(WorksheetName As String, Runtype As String, Language As String) As String

    Call Find_String(Runtype, WorksheetName)

    Runtype_Row = Selection.Row

    Call Find_String(Language, WorksheetName)

    Language_Column = Selection.Column

    Cell_Address = Cells(Runtype_Row, Language_Column).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

End Function
______________________

Public Sub Find_String(Search_String As String, WorksheetName As String)

    Sheets(WorksheetName).Select

    Cells.Find(What:=Search_String, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

End Sub
```

As you can see, I just select the sheet before looking up my string (in Find_String). It's maybe not the most elegant/efficient solution but at least it works.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to get this a little closer to what I think you are intending:

```
'Sub to run the code and call the other routines
Public Sub runthecode()

    Dim ID As Range, Result As Range

    ResultLocation = Cell_Address("Pass Rates", "Functional Text", "fra-FRA")
    IDLocation = Cell_Address("Regression URLs", "Text-Based Functional", "fra-FRA")

    MsgBox ResultLocation

End Sub

-------
' Sub to find, by 2 way look up, the address of a cell

Public Function Cell_Address(WorksheetName As String, Runtype As String, Language As String) As String

    With Sheets(WorksheetName)
        Call Find_String(Runtype, Sheets(WorksheetName))
        Runtype_Row = Selection.Row     
        Language_Column = Find_String(Language, Sheets(WorksheetName))
        Cell_Address = .Cells(Runtype_Row, Language_Column).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
        MsgBox Cell_Address

    End With

End Function

-------
' Function to find a specific string and return the column in which it can be found

Public Function Find_String(Search_String As String, ws as worksheet) as Range 'returns column

    Find_String = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Search_String, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, 
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, 
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

End Sub
```

I've changed that `Find_String` to be a function that will return a range representing the Column in which the string was found. This way we aren't relying on Activating and Selection.

We are also passing the `Find_String` function the worksheet that we are interested in so it will know what `Cells()` you are referencing.

Lastly, The With block now has some use where we say `.Cells()` to set the `Cell_Address`.

I can't guarantee this does exactly what you want, but it should get you over the hurdles you are facing now and a little closer to whatever the end goal is.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JNevill for your inputs ! I managed to resolve my code and use the sheet name now. However I have an additional issue that maybe you could help me with. I am able to get the location of the cell I want in string form by using the function Cell_Address but I want that string to get me a  range or the value of a range. Using : Set ID = Sheets("Pass Rates").Range(Cell_Address("Pass Rates", "Functional Text", "fra-FRA")).Value doesn't work though... I don't understand why because doing Range("A1") would amount to the same since I literally get that with Cell_Address().

Comment: For one `ID` is going to hold a `string` not a `range` because `Cell_ADdress()` returns a string. So declare it correctly `Dim ID as String` then don't use `Set` to assign it's vallue as it's not an object. `ID = Cells_Address(...)`

Comment: I didn't know that it would need to be set as a string. Thanks for the tip, but it's very weird, I have content in the cell and when I do `IDLocation = Cell_Address("Regression URLs", "Text-Based Functional", "fra-FRA")` then `ID = Sheets("Pass Rates").Range(IDLocation).Value` and then I check with `MsgBox ID` and `MsgBox IDLocation`, i get blank for the 1st msg and then "F30" for the second. So it's pointing to the right location but somehow doesn't get the value through... I don't have an error message either :s

Comment: Are you sure that "Pass Rates" has something in F30?

Comment: Checked again, I was pointing to the wrong work sheet, guess I'm not as attentive as I thought I was :) It all works now !